# TCP/IP Android Device Connectivity Issues

Tags: java, android, client

I have a tcp/ip application in which Client 'A' gets it's coordinates and sends them to the server running on my pc.  I am using local ips etc.  This was running fine, I came out this morning however and I had an issue with my tp-link router and the lan, so I re installed my router and all connections (wi-fi) are back up and running.  However, now when I try to run my app it won't work with my device.

If I run it through the emulator (i just have a string for testing) it works, I know that this is because both the server and the emulator are both on the same machine.  My ip is correct, it is that of the machine the server is running on...I'm trying to teach myself this technology and do a project for college and I keep coming up against massive headaches like this.  I've posted my client and server code below, is there anyone that might have any ideas?  All setting are the same on the router and i'm sure as this is just connecting over a lan I don't have to forward any ports?

**CLIENT A**

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Child extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private Socket s;
    private PrintWriter p;
    public static double latitude;
    public static double longitude;
    String coordinates;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.child);

        LocationManager mlocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        mlocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mlocationListener);         

        String hello = "hello";  //FOR TESTING PURPOSES

        Transmit (hello);

        Log.d("test", "test");
    }



   public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             latitude = location.getLatitude();
             longitude = location.getLongitude();

             coordinates = ("TESTING " + latitude + longitude);

             //Transmit(coordinates);         
        }   
    }

    private void Transmit(final String message) {

        Thread trans = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Log.d("TRANSMIT", "CALLED");

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                    s = new Socket("192.168.3.103", 1111); // connect to
                                                            // server
                    Log.d("CONNECTED", "Connected");

                    DataOutputStream _OutPut = new DataOutputStream(
                            s.getOutputStream());
                    _OutPut.writeBytes(message + "\n");
                    _OutPut.flush();
                    _OutPut.close();

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        trans.start();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

**SERVER**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TCPServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Socket s;       
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1111);

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 2001");
        System.out.println("Server: waiting for connection ..");

        while (true) {
            try {
                s = ss.accept();        

                if (s != null) {

                    InputStream fromChild = s.getInputStream();

                    while (s.isConnected()) {

                        System.out.println("Child Connected");              

                        Scanner r = new Scanner(fromChild);
                        String location;
                        location = r.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(location);

                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So please, if anyone can help or throw some light on the situation I would be extremely grateful as I can't develop any further until I sort this problem.

Regards, 
Gary

Comment: Update your question headings with summary specifying your problem

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html read about the Emulator Networking and network address space there carefully

Answer (score 0):

It certainly sounds like a connectivity issue between the phone and the server.

- Double-check your ip address on the server and the phone and make sure they are on the SAME SUBNET (192.168.3.X), if not then you need to set up a forwarding rule on the router.
- You can also verify connectivity by running a basic html server on the server box and point the browser on the phone to the server.  Apache tomcat right of the box is easy to start and has a dashboard app already configured to run on startup. You can also test this from another computer on the same network to rule out your code and the phone altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

an excerpt from there :

Network Address Description
10.0.2.1    Router/gateway address

10.0.2.2    Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

10.0.2.3    First DNS server

10.0.2.4 / 10.0.2.5 / 10.0.2.6  Optional second, third and fourth DNS server (if any)

10.0.2.15   The emulated device's own network/ethernet interface

127.0.0.1   The emulated device's own loopback interface

---

basically if you run your server locally you should try and hit 10.0.2.2 address
from the emulator ---

Cheers,